# Condition if AB=0 if A,B are square matrices of same order

Tags: matrices, abelian-categories

Prove that if $AB=0$ then either $A$ or $B$ is null matrix or both are singular. 
I am unable to submit my working as i have no udea how to proceed. I can only think of taking mod and saying $|AB|=0$ . I am able to understand the null matrix part as all elements would be $0$ in $AB$. Can someone help me in the second part?

Comment: Please use elementary methods as I have very little knowledge of the topic.

Comment: 1. The question's title is not clear enough. 2. Please use Mathjax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing AB=0 does not imply either A,B=0, but that singular](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783593/showing-ab-0-does-not-imply-either-a-b-0-but-that-singular)

Comment: It didn't properly address the condition that both can be singular( or it may have, maybe i didn't understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume that neither $A$ and $B$ is the null matrix. What we need to prove is that

> If $AB = 0$, then both $A$ and $B$ is singular.

This is the same as proving

> If one of $A$ and $B$ is not singular, then $AB\neq 0$.

This should be easier to prove.

---

Let's say that $A$ is not singular.

Then,

- take some $x$ such that $Bx\neq 0$ (*why does this $x$ exist?*).
- What is $ABx$? (*is it $0$?*)
- Can you therefore conclude that $AB\neq 0$?

---

Now, assume that $B$ is not singular. Since you know there exists some $y$ such that $Ay\neq 0$ (again, *why*?), can you find an $x$ such that $(AB)x\neq 0$?

**Hint**:
Remember, $(AB)x = A(Bx)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to proving that, if $AB=0$ and one of $A,B$ is non-singular, the other matrix is $0$.

Suppose $A$ is non-singular. Then it is invertible and left-multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$  yields 
$$0=A^{-1}(AB)=(A^{-1}A)B=IB=B.$$
Similarly, if $B$ is non-singular, you right-multiply by $B^{-1}$ to ge $A=0$.